# New keyboard for programming wanted

Tags: keyboards

Years back I bought the cheapest Logitech keyboard for my computer as I felt they "are all the same!". I hadn't used it in a while, but since working from home now I'm using a lot and it has really dawned on me the last couple of weeks just how loud and stiff the keys are. I'm pretty certain my neighbour two doors down can here me tapping at the keys it's that loud. Each key feels like a brick when I'm pressing it so I really need to upgrade.

What are people on here using or could recommend? I'll be primarily using it for programming, with some use of Photoshop and gaming at some point.

Comment: Are you searching for a mechanical keyboard? There are mechanical switches that are rather silent. It will be hard to make a clear recommendation based on the rather vague information you gave. And in the end, the right keyboard is a question of personal preference. I really like the Cherry Sream 3.0 keyboard. The quality is solid given the 25€ price point, and I prefer the shorter key travel and the feel of a rubberdome over all mechanical switches I tried in the past. Maybe because it feels very similar to the older Thinkpad keyboards...

Comment: I'm not pushed on whether it's mechanical or not. I'd like something that feels nice when you type, is somewhat quiet and which the keys are relatively light. I do agree it's probably down to personal preference, but with all the shops closed I can't get out anywhere to try some out. Like you mention the shorter key travel for me would be a biggie, as currently it feel's like I'm pressing down two inches.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went with the Logitech K800. Watched many videos of top rated keyboards and many were still as loud, if not louder than my current one. Even top mechanical ones with low key were surprisingly loud in the videos. The K800 was extrememly quiet and although well above my initial budget, it seemed to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=cherry+switches+red+blue+black has a number of videos and articles you may find helpful in making a decision.

I would suggest a keyboard with Cherry Speed Silver switches in your case for their shorter travel, e.g.:

https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/shop/index.php?l=product_list&c=363

https://www.keyboardco.com/keyboard/usa-v80-tenkeyless-speed-switch-vintage-keyboard.asp

[https://www.amazon.com/Mechanical-Keyboard-Switches-Lighting-Stealth/dp/B07VXRXMHF/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VXRXMHF)

[https://www.amazon.com/CORSAIR-K70-MK-2-RAPIDFIRE-Profile/dp/B07D5S24BP/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D5S24BP)

[https://www.amazon.com/PLATINUM-Mechanical-Keyboard-Passthrough-Controls/dp/B01N5IISXY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N5IISXY)

[https://www.amazon.com/CORSAIR-Mechanical-Keyboard-Backlit-Resistant/dp/B07QBD76TX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QBD76TX)

Comment: After looking through a number of those videos I found many of those keyboards still quite loud. Many keyboard articles mentioned the logitech K800, and after watching some videos of it I decided to go with that one. Looks really nice and is certainly far more quiet than other keyboards. Probably not the best for gaming but will do. Bought it off the logitech websiter for £99.